# error on autoreleasepool line

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just started with objective c, I have an example in a book that I should follow, but I got an error and I don't know how to fix it. [here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgQSu.png)

EDIT: Okay I placed the two missing brackets {} on the proper place but now I have another two errors!

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMeVh.png)

Comment: If you have a problem, post it.

Comment: Missing `{` and `}`. It should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{@autoreleasepool {
/*Your code about fraction*/}}`

Answer (score 0):

Read the book more carefully ;-)

The opening brace `{` **before** the `@autoreleasepool` line and the closing brace `}` before the `return 0` line are missing